# Jquery/CSS: 100% height div resizes even though overflow is auto

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/34tuuq2o/

The div resizes even though I have `overflow-y` set to `auto` and I gave the div a height (although this height **does not appear in the firebug DOM viewer**).

How can I get the div to activate the scroll-bar instead of resizing?

Also, do I have to set a height for the container ( `height: 90%;` )?

```js
$('[type=button]').click(function() {
  $('#chat').append("<p>text</p>");
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}
#chatDiv {
  background-color: #F2D9AA;
  background-color: rgba(242, 217, 170, 1);
  font: 18px serif black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 50%;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#chatDiv > .container {
  height: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
#chat {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#chatInput {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #AD8539;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatInput .container {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
#chatInput[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: 18px serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="chatDiv">
  <div class="block container">
    <div id="chat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="chatInput">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="chatTI" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='append'></input>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific..which div do you need to have scrollbar and dont want it to resize ?

Comment: @RahulSambari The div with class `container`, I would like to know if I *need* to resize it. And the div with class `chat` should have a scroll-bar.

Comment: change height of id = chat to some pixels and not percentage..adding percentage would make it responsive (i am not sure exacly) . Let me know is that you are looking for for scrollbar?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/34tuuq2o/ is this what you are looking ? did i get your question right ?

Comment: @RahulSambari You need to save that as a new fiddle, otherwise it just shows mine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsambari/34tuuq2o/6/ ..try this

Comment: @RahulSambari I'm trying to avoid using a pixel size for the div because I don't know how big a user's screen will be...

Comment: ok ..can you give any fixed height i.e. in pixels to class="block container" ?

Comment: @RahulSambari `chatDiv` has a fixed minimum height. Is that enough? I've never needed to set heights (in pixels) before, because I've always inherited the percentages from the main, absolute, wrapper div... Why do I need it now?

Comment: hmmm i am not sure either..actually i am totally skeptical that scrollbar will appear when we are designing it to be responsive i.e. using percentages..as i have tried similar functionality and i have spent long time to achieve that but could not.

Comment: @StrongJoshua - You can add a snippet by selecting the Stack Snippet option (the pencil image) in the [editor tools](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uj26u.png).

Comment: hey @StrongJoshua ..what was the change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me how, I just tried things, but this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/o6d3644L/

```js
$('[type=button]').click(function() {
  $('#chat').append("<p>text</p>");
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}
#chatDiv {
  background-color: rgba(242, 217, 170, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font: 18px serif black;
  max-height: 50%;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatDiv .container {
  bottom: 10%;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#chat {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatInput {
  border-top: 1px solid #ad8539;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 90%;
}
#chatInput .container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
#chatInput[type="text"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: medium none;
  font: 18px serif;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="chatDiv">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="chat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="chatInput">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="chatTI" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='append'></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need modify css, main change is:

set `html` and `body` `height: 100%`

set `#chatDiv` `height: 50%`

set `.container` `position: absolute`

try this:

```js
$('[type=button]').click(function() {
  $('#chat').append("<p>text</p>");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
#chatDiv {
  background-color: #F2D9AA;
  background-color: rgba(242, 217, 170, 1);
  font: 18px serif black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#chatDiv > .container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
}
#chat {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#chatInput {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #AD8539;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#chatInput .container {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
#chatInput[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: 18px serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="chatDiv">
  <div class="block container">
    <div id="chat"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="chatInput">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="chatTI" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='append'></input>
```

Comment: But setting position to absolute defeats the purpose of the wrapper, which was to add the margin while still being able to set the inner div to `height: 100%`... Also, how did you do the Run code snippet thing at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by reducing our HTML markup a little.

We need:

- A chat wrapper to keep the chat elements contained - the class is `.chat`
- The conversation of our chat - the class is `.conversation` which will scroll
- The input - the class is `.input`

To display our chat window nicely:

- `html,body { height: 100%; }` allows elements to have a percentage height
- `.chat` is given a height of 50% (of the 100% height on html,body)
- The child of chat - `.conversation` - is given a height of 90% (of its parent `.chat`'s height) and the input div gets the remainder 10%
- `overflow-y: scroll` hides the overflow of `.conversation` and displays a scrollbar.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```js
$('[type=button]').click(function() {
  $('.conversation').append("<p>text</p>");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.chat {
  height: 50%;
}
.conversation {
  background-color: #F2D9AA;
  background-color: rgba(242, 217, 170, 1);
  font: 18px serif black;
  height: 90%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.input {
  background-color: #F2D9AA;
  background-color: rgba(242, 217, 170, 1);
  border-top: solid 1px #AD8539;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <div class="conversation"></div>

  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="chat-input" />
    <button type='button'>Append</button>
  </div>
</div>
```